# React Router and useContext not working together

Tags: reactjs, router, use-context

When I'm trying to read data, it is successfully logged in console in every file except in my SwitchRouter.tsx and I don't know why. What I'm trying to do is get value of user(isLogin) and based on that value conditionally render component. (If user is logged in, then user have access to UserContact, UserPosts and AboutMe, and if user is not logged in, then he has access to HomePage only)

NavigationBar.tsx

```
function NavigationBar() {

    const { user } = useContext(LoginUserContext)

    console.log('nav bar', user)                      // working fine

    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <NavLinkRouter />
                <SwitchRouter />
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavigationBar
```

```
function SwitchRouter() {

    const { user } = useContext(LoginUserContext)

    console.log('switch route', user)                    // not displaying anything

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/contacts" render={() => (user.isLogin ? <UserContact /> : <Redirect to="/" />)} />
            <Route path="/posts" render={() => (user.isLogin ? <UserPosts /> : <Redirect to="/" />)} />
            <Route path="/aboutme" render={() => (user.isLogin ? <AboutMe /> : <Redirect to="/" />)} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default SwitchRouter
```

```
function NavLinkRouter() {

    const history = useHistory()


    const handleLogin = () => {
        history.push('/Login')
        if(user.isLogin) {
            setUser({...user, isLogin: false})
            history.push('/')
        }
    }

    const { user, setUser } = useContext(LoginUserContext)

    console.log('nav link', user)                         //working fine

    return (
        <div className="navBar">
            <ul>
                <li><NavLink className="navlink" activeStyle={{ color: 'rgb(52,48,76)' }} strict to="/" exact>Home Page</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="navlink" activeStyle={{ color: 'rgb(52,48,76)' }} strict to="/contacts" >User Contacts</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="navlink" activeStyle={{ color: 'rgb(52,48,76)' }} strict to="/posts" >Posts</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="navlink" activeStyle={{ color: 'rgb(52,48,76)' }} strict to="/aboutme" >About Me</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
            <button className="btnLogin" onClick={handleLogin}>{user.isLogin ? 'Logout' : 'Login'}</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavLinkRouter
```

Why is only in SwitchRouter.tsx not displaying anything? And how can I get that value of user to use it for conditional rendering?

Here is snippet
[image]

Comment: Are you saying not even the `"switch route"` get logged to the console? Are you sure  you are importing the right `SwitchRouter` file?

Comment: Yes, nothing is logged to the console in that file. And yes I imported the right file, if I remove "SwitchRouter" from "Navigationbar.tsx" I don't see other pages, they don't have any content, if I add it then I see everything

Comment: That is really strange. Could you create a simple reproduction on codesandbox?

Comment: If I delete <Switch><Switch/> componet in "SwitchRouter.tsx" and replace it with a <div></div> I get message logged to the console, so I assume that the problem is with <Switch> or <Route>?

Comment: Do you have another Switch somewhere up in your component tree?

Comment: Nope, but... I really don't know what the hell happened, but suddenly it is working.. and I literally didn't changed a thing but yeah haha thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Marina what was the culprit? did you solve your problem?